# How to calculate the max number of evenly spaced points on a grid

Tags: algorithm, maze

I need to create a grid that has x columns, y rows, where each cell in the grid can have a point in it, and each point is at least z horizontal/vertical spaces away from all other points.

1) Is there a simple method to calculate the maximum number of points I can place given the grid size and a spacing of z?

Here's an example 5x5 with z = 2. In this case the max number of points is 13.

```
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

and here's an example 5x5 where z = 3.  In this case the max number of points is 6.

```
1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
```

I'd like to be able, given x, y, and z, the number of points possible to plot.

2) What's the most efficient way of populating the grid in this manner?

Comment: would putting a point in a border matter? Will be z spaces away from other points but it might not look "evenly spaced"

Comment: Your notion of distance really is x + y and not the standard Euclidean distance?  How big a grid are you aiming for?

Comment: Yeah, distances is the number of horizontal/vertical moves it takes to get to the cell in question.  The grid could be arbitrarily large, but I think we can assume it fits in main memory.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Actually, let me retract that upvote for greedy. Consider a 5x4 grid with distance 3. Going top-to-bottom and left-to-right and adding points at the earliest possibility would result in 10010, 00000, 01001, 00000 = 4, while 10001, 00100, 00000, 10001 = 5 would have been better.